# Pack a GLib.Variant in Python

Tags: python, glib

The PyGObject API allows to convert a GLib Variant to a Python object using the `unpack()` method (see [GLib.Variant.unpack](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GLib-2.0/classes/Variant.html#GLib.Variant.unpack)).

However, is there a direct way to do the reverse?

E.g. I can create arbitrary GLib Variant objects using the Variant constructors:

```
>>> myglibvariant = GLib.Variant("a{sv}", { 'test': GLib.Variant('s', 'value')})
```

And use the `unpack()` function to create a Python object in one step:

```
>>> myglibvariant.unpack()
{'test': 'value'}
```

However, is there a way to do the reverse in one step? E.g.

```
>>> myglibvariant = GLib.Variant.pack({'test': 'value'})
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because you have to specify the type. (In the `{'test': 'value'}` example, the pack function would have to guess whether the type is `a{ss}` or `a{sv}`, or possibly `{ss}` or `{sv}` as well.

Comment: Good point, type ambiguity makes it impossible to guess the type right. However, if the type is given, it should be possible, shouldn't it? E.g. `GLib.Variant.pack("a{sv}", {'test': 'value'})`

Comment: That function is the `GLib.Variant` constructor, no?

Comment: No, when trying to use the above example (`GLib.Variant("a{sv}", {'test': 'value'})`) it fails with `TypeError: argument value: Expected GLib.Variant, but got str`.

Comment: I think it could be smart and just make `'value'` a variant. It seems that `unpack()` is doing the reverse, it converts the variant to a string...

Comment: If it automatically wrapped `'value'` into a variant, it still wouldn't know what type to make the variant; it could be `'s'`, `'o'`, or `'g'`.

Comment: Hm, I see, the GLib type system has really more types than what Python has, and that does not allow to make a reliable conversion back to GLib. It could take guesses, but then it would not be guaranteed that the output would be the same as the original variant.

Comment: FWIW, in my use case I had to replace a single value in a `a{sv}`, where `v` can have unknown structures. I ended up staying away from using `unpack()`. Instead I peak into the data using `get_child_value()` and friends, change the one value I am interested in and pass all other array entries as `GLib.Variant` to my the new `a{sv}` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can find simple pack implementation in GNOME browser connector project: https://gitlab.gnome.org/nE0sIghT/gnome-browser-connector/-/blob/fb3e8feb7c9c9f8d6442b789531bf7926e930f3f/gnome_browser_connector/helpers.py#L8